# jquery booklet lib - how to display a cover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[jquery booklet lib](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/) allows creating an HTML5 flipbook with turning pages effects.
None of the direct options in the [documentation](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/documentation) seem to allow displaying a cover image. It does have a `closedFrontTitle` option.
Any idea how to set a cover image?

Comment: Managed to do it, here's the code snippet:

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it. 
It turns out the "closed:false" displays the covers (would have been nice if it would have been 'covers:true', but anyhow...

Here's the code snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mybook').show();
    $('#mybook').booklet({pageNumbers:false, arrows: true, hoverWidth: 120, closed: false, startingPage: 7, direction: "LTR", height: 675, width: 860});

});
```